# How to point to existing blockchain data in docker?

Tags: node, docker, bootstrapping

I moved my docker container to a new partition for more space and started the alphanet. It started syncing from the beginning instead of using the bootstrapped data I transferred in the container. How do I point to the existing bootstrapped/synced data that I transferred?